# How to open files in one instance using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I edit files directly from FTP and like to use Visual Studio, however VS seems to open each file in a new instance of VS instead of a new tab. I believe this is because it's a file without a solution/project.

How can I force VS to open multiple separate files inside one multitabed window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should perhaps look into this command line option : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa991989(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for a useful hint! Not what I was looking for but a very big hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem This worked for me :

In Filezilla go to Edit > Settings > File editing 
on the "Use custom editor" radio button, enter the following:
**NB: the space between quatation mark and forword slash is important**
**" /edit**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /edit
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /edit
```